# Hide delete button in Modern team site SharePoint Online library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, permissions, delete

How can I hide delete button in modern team site library `allitems.aspx` page.

I don't want to remove delete permission.

Because I am planning to run a workflow on item deleting. So I am planning to hide  default delete button and using list action I want to run a workflow.

Is there any solution to run a work flow on default delete button?

Answer (score 2):

Except removing Delete permission, in general, we can consider using CSS/JavaScript code. However,currently, CSS/JavaScript is not supported for "modern" lists and libraries. So, except managing permissions, I am afraid there is not another way to hide Delete Button.

[Customizing "modern" lists and libraries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries)